# Format string with arabic numbers to normal numbers

Tags: java, android, localization, locale, string-formatting

I'm having this string that in it have some arabic numbers that are causing some issues to my app. So what I need is to format(replace) the numbers to the original ones, like this:

```
//Arabic numbers:
http://example.com/mmm/michaeljackson/٠٠٣.mp3
//I want this to be converted like this:
http://example.com/mmm/michaeljackson/002.mp3
```

Right now I am doing this, but the string locale is staying the same

```
String.format(Locale.US, playlistSongs.get(playPosition).getLink())
```

Can someone help me solve this issue

Comment: What you call arabic numbers are hindi numbers. What you call 'normal' numbers are arabic numbers.

Comment: `String` is immutable. Try this : `String result = String.format(Locale.US, playlistSongs.get(playPosition).getLink())`

Comment: @JihedAmine as I have been told these are old arabic numbers - the guy who told me knows this - but lets focus on the issue here

Comment: @ChetanKinger nope it doesnt work.. Im doing this `String result = String.format(Locale.US, playlistSongs.get(playPosition).getLink());` but link stays the same

Comment: I tried to make it easy with this [light library](https://github.com/ALI-KH-Y/AnyNum).